# Amazon web service with item lookup by UPC

Tags: c#, amazon-product-api

My working envirnment is Visual Studio 2008 + C#

I am working on Amazon WebService, I want to fetch the data from Amazon using SOAP but when I am trying to pass IDType = UPC it gives me below error message, so what can I do for this ?

Error:

> 036725229884 is not a valid value for ItemId. Please change this value and retry your request

**MyCode:**

```
ItemLookupRequest request1 = new ItemLookupRequest();
request1.IdType = ItemLookupRequestIdType.UPC;
request1.IdTypeSpecified = true;
request1.ItemId = new string[] { ProductID };
request1.ResponseGroup = new string[] { "Request", "Large", "OfferFull", "BrowseNodes" };
request1.MerchantId = "All";
request1.Condition = Condition.All;
request1.SearchIndex = "Books";
```

**Note:**
How can I add multiple SearchIndex like ("Books","Photo","Video")?

I have used following WebService:
http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-11-01/US/AWSECommerceService.wsdl

Answer (score 2):

Also be weary of the difference between UPC and EAN.

> UPC = 12 digits, 
>    EAN = 13 digits

If you just punch in a UPC `738678251584` (12 digits) or EAN `3253581057803` (13 digits) to Amazon.com it will show both as being UPC in the description, but using the API you must specify EAN when searching.

We have products with both and you need to specify the search type accordingly or it won't get found.

**Edit**: OR you can just prepend a 0 to any 12 digit numbers and always search for EAN. This is probably the best solution. By definition ["0" + UPC = EAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code)

This request worked for me (searchType is either UPC or EAN):

```
        ItemLookup itemLookup = new ItemLookup()
        {
            AssociateTag = "XXXXX-20",
        };
        itemLookup.AWSAccessKeyId = ACCESS_ID;

        ItemLookupRequest itemLookupRequest = new ItemLookupRequest();
        itemLookupRequest.IdTypeSpecified = true;
        itemLookupRequest.IdType = searchType;
        itemLookupRequest.SearchIndex = "All";
        itemLookupRequest.ItemId = upcEanList;
        itemLookupRequest.ResponseGroup = new[] { "OfferSummary", "ItemAttributes" };
        itemLookup.Request = new ItemLookupRequest[] { itemLookupRequest };
```

Comment: read this too : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code
particularly the EAN section

Comment: "A UPC barcode XXXXXXXXXXXX therefore is the EAN-13 barcode 0XXXXXXXXXXXX"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Amazon supports queries across multiple search indices. However, there is a [special index named `All`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/index.html?USSearchIndexParamForItemsearch.html) that you can use with UPC lookups. There are some limitations on the parameters used with this index but since you are specifying `All` for `MerchantId` and `Condition` it may work. If not, you could do the query without those parameters and then issue a new query once you have the ASINs for the UPCs you are interested in.